# passing multiple lists to pandas.Series

Tags: python-3.x

This is the very simple code I wrote to begin with pandas.

```
import pandas
lst = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
lst2 = [5,6,7,5,6,7]
lst3 = [1,2,3,10,20,30] 
s = pandas.Series(lst,lst2,lst3)
```

The output gives the error: `datatype not understood`.
Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: what are you really looking for

Comment: The output popped up error: data type not understood...but I got it later! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create pandas Series object is to use a list as you're trying:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
lst2 = [5,6,7,5,6,7]
lst3 = [1,2,3,10,20,30]
#But pandas series object accept only one argument for data. there are others like #index,name, etc
pd.Series(lst + lst2 + lst3)
#creates a series 
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      1
4      2
5      3
6      5
7      6
8      7
9      5
10     6
11     7
12     1
13     2
14     3
15    10
16    20
17    30
```

Answer (score 1):

use numpy concatenate. use set if the numbers need to be unique

```
lst = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
lst2 = [5,6,7,5,6,7]
lst3 = [1,2,3,10,20,30]

result=np.concatenate([lst,lst2,lst3],axis=0)
print(result)
```

output:

```
[ 1  2  3  1  2  3  5  6  7  5  6  7  1  2  3 10 20 30]
```